# Reverse an array of objects

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I have a static class containing arrays of objects.

```
public static Waypoint[] AtoB
        {
            get
            {
                return new Waypoint[] {
                    new Waypoint(49.251f,-851.837f),
                    new Waypoint(66.7397f,-843.165f),
                    new Waypoint(77.8777f,-825.462f)
                };
            }
        }
```

Now I want to create another array of Waypoint called BtoA that is the same as AtoB but reverse order. So something like:

```
public static Waypoint[] BtoA
    {
        get { return AtoB.Reverse(); }
    }
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can save reversed sequence to new array with [ToArray()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb298736%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension call:

```
return AtoB.Reverse().ToArray();
```

In this case you will have two arrays in memory - you will have array returned by `AtoB` property, then you will create reverse iterator for that array, and finally you will save reversed sequence to completely new array.

Or you can reverse original array with [Array.Reverse(array)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3877932%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var array = AtoB;
Array.Reverse(array);
return array;
```

In this case you will have single array which was created in `AtoB` property - you just reverse items of that array instance.

NOTE: Your code is not working, because [Reverse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension creates `ReverseIterator` which is not an array - it is of type `IEnumerable<Waypoint>`. So, one more option for you is changing type of `BtoA` property to `IEnumerable<Waypoint>`.

Comment: thanks, works perfectly. also, can you explain the difference between `Obj[].Reverse().ToArray()` and `Array.Reverse(Obj[])`?

Comment: @user2914191 in first case you will have two arrays in memory - one which created in your property, then you will create reverse enumerator for that array, and finally you will save reversed sequence to completely new array. In second case you have single array which was created in property - you just reverse items of that array.

Comment: @user2914191 side note - if you need to return array with constant data, you can just create static variable with that array data `public static readonly Waypoint[] AtoB = new [] {  new Waypoint(49.251f,-851.837f), new Waypoint(66.7397f,-843.165f), new Waypoint(77.8777f,-825.462f) };` thus you can reuse same array instead of creating new one each time, but in that case should go with option #1 for reversing it

Answer (score 0):

Well, use the [Enumerable.Reverse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function:

```
public static Waypoint[] BtoA
{
    get { AtoB.Reverse().ToArray();; 
}
```

Don't forget to add the using statement:

```
using System.Linq
```